# How to get each stream data of pdf file?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm working on a pdf decrypt task.

The pdf provider/vendor encrypts each stream data by their own method. And they provide decrypt function as well.

I verified that the decrypt function works correctly on one stream data. But the pdf file could have many streams, so I need to extract each stream data and feed it to the decrypt function.

Below is one of the stream from the decrypted pdf file:

```
6 0 obj
<</Length 608/Filter[/VendorPDFEncrypt/FlateDecode]>>stream
data_1
endstream
endobj
```

And the pdf vendor provides the decrypted pdf file to me, so I find the corresponding stream in it, as below. As you can see, vendor added filter disappears and the data part changes.

```
2 0 obj
<</Filter[/FlateDecode]/Length 598>>stream
data_2
endstream
endobj
```

**Summay process:**

```
encrypted pdf file -> extract each stream data -> feed it to decrypt function repeatedly-> get a readable pdf file
```

**My question is how to extract each stream data from the pdf file?**
So I can use the decrypt function to handle each stream data.

Comment: You have tagged your question [tag:itext]. Thus, I assume you try to extract data with iText. Unfortunately you don't mention the iText version you use. I assume a current 7.x or even the 8.0.0-SNAPSHOT development version. In that case the streams are in `PdfStream` objects which have a `GetBytes(bool decoded)` method. With `decoded == false` you should be able to retrieve the raw data from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the PDF file to JSON like this, including the streams of compressed data:

`cpdf -output-json in.pdf -o out.json`

Then, when you have processed the JSON to decompress the stream, you can check by roundtripping back to PDF:

`cpdf -j new.json -o out.pdf`